# FOR XML: conditional empty nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, sql-server-2012

There is an SQL query:

```
WITH q1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS c1, 2 AS c2, 'three' AS c3, 'orange' AS row_type
    UNION ALL SELECT 11, 22, 'thirty three', 'banana'
    UNION ALL SELECT 111, 222, 'three hundred thirty three', 'apple'
) SELECT q1.c1
       , q1.c2
       , q1.c3
       , q1.row_type FROM q1 FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('doc'),type
```

It returns:

```
<doc>
  <row>
    <c1>1</c1>
    <c2>2</c2>
    <c3>three</c3>
    <row_type>orange</row_type>
  </row>
  <row>
    <c1>11</c1>
    <c2>22</c2>
    <c3>thirty three</c3>
    <row_type>banana</row_type>
  </row>
  <row>
    <c1>111</c1>
    <c2>222</c2>
    <c3>three hundred thirty three</c3>
    <row_type>apple</row_type>
  </row>
</doc>
```

I need it to return:

```
<doc>
  <row>
    <c1>1</c1>
    <c2>2</c2>
    <c3>three</c3>
    <row_type>
        <orange />
    </row_type>
  </row>
  <row>
    <c1>11</c1>
    <c2>22</c2>
    <c3>thirty three</c3>
    <row_type>
        <banana />
    </row_type>
  </row>
  <row>
    <c1>111</c1>
    <c2>222</c2>
    <c3>three hundred thirty three</c3>
    <row_type>
        <apple />
    </row_type>
  </row>
</doc>
```

I.e. I want to create a conditional empty node for each `<row>`, with the name of the node being driven off another attribute of the current record.

Any hints how to approach this?

SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general answer is: *Don't!*

It is always a very bad idea to let an element's name be data. Much better was

```
<row_type type="apple" />
```

But you might trick this somehow along one of these:

--This query works, when you know all needed values in advance.
--The magic is, that XML will omit NULL values by default

```sql
WITH q1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS c1, 2 AS c2, 'three' AS c3, 'orange' AS row_type
    UNION ALL SELECT 11, 22, 'thirty three', 'banana'
    UNION ALL SELECT 111, 222, 'three hundred thirty three', 'apple'
) 
SELECT q1.c1
     , q1.c2
     , q1.c3
     , CASE WHEN q1.row_type='orange' THEN '' END AS [row_type/orange] 
     , CASE WHEN q1.row_type='banana' THEN '' END AS [row_type/banana] 
     , CASE WHEN q1.row_type='apple' THEN '' END AS [row_type/apple] 
FROM q1 
FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('doc'),type;
```

--This query uses some string-concatenation and a CAST

```sql
WITH q1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS c1, 2 AS c2, 'three' AS c3, 'orange' AS row_type
    UNION ALL SELECT 11, 22, 'thirty three', 'banana'
    UNION ALL SELECT 111, 222, 'three hundred thirty three', 'apple'
) 
SELECT q1.c1
     , q1.c2
     , q1.c3
     --careful, if your "row_type" might not be a valid element name
     , CAST(CONCAT('<',q1.row_type,'/>') AS XML) AS [row_type] 
FROM q1 
FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('doc'),type;
```

Comment: I can't agree with you more, this is not the best practice. However, we're all living in some business realities where 3rd party specifications have to be followed even though they are not perfect. Thanks for CAST based solution, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: @shnugo, your first method worked like a charm. Ignoring NULLs by default helps a lot. Problem solved. Thanks again!